# Using Firefox does not work with the Java-Client, Chrome works well

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenoid

Using a java client I experienced an error if I was using the firefox capability. Chrome worked well though.

In the telegram support chat I found out that my selenium client version was too old for using firefox 55-56 (client: 3.0.1). Updating to the latest client version resolved my error.

Maybe someone from Aerokube could get into more detail why it failed with the old client.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox with versions more than *55* requires **geckodriver** older than *0.18*. On page https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases you can find complete changelog with notes about compatibility.

Even version *0.15.0* has notice:

> IMPORTANT: If you use geckodriver with Selenium, you must upgrade to
>   Selenium 3.3 since this release aligns HTTP responses with the
>   WebDriver standard.

Usually, it's safe to update client part in advance, as it works well with previous browser/driver versions too.